# Transclusion - change init order

Tags: angularjs

Is there a way to process **colors** earlier than **child** regardless it's position in parent?

This variant not working as expected

```
<control>
  <child col="red"></child>
  <child col="green"></child>
  <child col="blue"></child>
  <colors>
    <color name="red">#FF0000</color>
    <color name="green">#00FF00</color>
    <color name="blue">#0000FF</color>
  </colors>
</control>
```

This variant is ok

```
<control>
  <colors>
    <color name="red">#FF0000</color>
    <color name="green">#00FF00</color>
    <color name="blue">#0000FF</color>
  </colors>
  <child col="red"></child>
  <child col="green"></child>
  <child col="blue"></child>
</control>
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/AbyzbXdTXC5dAxo1DWWk?p=preview

And I don't want to wrap `scope.myColor = controlCtrl.colors[scope.color];` in $timeout. Maybe I can do something with pre and post linking? Or priority? Thx.

Btw, I'll be very grateful if you point me to a better solution for this example. I mean - a way to communicate between elements.

Comment: I think you should not rely on the order of the elements as this introduces implicitness in your code. isn't it possible to pass the control element a config JSON?

Comment: Yes, it's possible, but I really want to implement my config via tags.

Comment: In my real case I store validation rules for ngModel in tags. So I have constructions like <rule type="require">and here is a lot of html error text</rule>